# Shower pan drain leak

Tags: plumbing

After a nice shower today I went downstairs to see water running out of my can light below the shower. I rand water down the actual shower drain and the other upstairs showers for about 15 minutes so I concluded the leak was from the pan drain(down the sides of the pipe). When I went to go fix it though there is no nut like I have seen before. Just the abs pipe coming up with a rubber ring around it. Can I just replace that ring or using silicone around it? I am redoing the bathroom but not for a few months so need a temp fix 
[image: drain]

[image: Drain]

Answer (score 1):

Usually the rubber hub seals on the pipe. Since it appears it is not sealing I would clean it and give it a try with silicone.